# BX LR and ARM return from exception instructions (RFE and ERET)

Tags: android, arm, armv7

In ARM architecture, returning from exception can be done in two ways which I know,(there might be others). But main logic is to modify PC, which will make processor trigger into mode set in CPSR.

So pop {...,pc} would make a switch to say user from supervisor 
or mov pc,lr would do the same.

My Question is, would a BX lr make the switch ?
Assuming I am handling IRQ and I call a assembly routine say do_IRQ and then return from do_IRQ is via BX LR. Would this make the code after bl do_IRQ in my fault handler irrelevant ?

```
irq_fault_handler:
    push    {lr}
    push {ro-r12}
    mrs     r0, spsr
    push    {r0}

     bl do_IRQ

     pop {r0}
     msr  cpsr, r0
     pop {r0,-r12}
     pop {lr}
     subs pc, lr, #4


do_IRQ:
...
BX LR
```

Comment: Note: This question was edited after the answer was accepted.  [Tangrs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/268025/tangrs) comments apply to the original post.  `mov pc,lr` was used as a return for instance.

Comment: The ARM ARM clearly defines the exact instruction you are supposed to use for each exception, yes?

Comment: Ahh, I see the newer ARM ARM's are different, they now say recommended return...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make it irrelevant since you called `do_IRQ` with `bl` instead of just a branch so you've already overwritten `lr`. Furthermore, even if you just did a branch, your stack would be messed up (you push r0-r12 but never pop them before returning).

Also, the code you show doesn't seem to return from the exception correctly either. Most of the time, when you return from an exception, you want to restore the program status registers as well as the registers which a `mov pc, lr` won't do nor will a `bx lr`.

Furthermore, the address contained in `lr` will actually be offsetted by a few words (it varies depending on the type of exception) so you're not returning to the correct instruction anyway. For IRQ, I believe it is off by 1 word.

The recommended way to return from an IRQ exception is a `subs pc, lr, #4` instruction (after you've pop'd all your registers beforehand of course) [which is special in that it also restores the CPSR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaiacfg.html).

Comment: You're restoring the SPSR, not the CPSR. Also, the lr address will still be wrong (it's one instruction ahead of the one you're supposed to be returning to). You should understand that returning from an exception is different to returning from a function.

Comment: Getting better but still has some issues. When you restore the CPSR, you're (possibly) changing processor modes and your stack will change and the pop will clobber your registers. Besides, it's all redundant. Just `push {r0-r12, lr}` at the start and `pop {r0-r12, lr}`, `subs pc, lr, #4` at the end. The `subs` instruction will restore the CPSR for you.

Comment: "subs instruction will restore the CPSR for you." I didnt get that. Can you please elaborate. Also how would the code change if I were to add a rfe or a eret

Comment: The `subs pc, lr, #4` is a [special `sub` instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaiacfg.html) that also restores the CPSR in addition to a normal subtract.

Comment: From a quick Google, it seems [`eret`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/CJAEEEJG.html) is equivalent to a `movs pc, lr` (which also restores the CPSR) but is really only used on ARM hypervisor platforms. It's probably fair to say you won't need to use this unless you're writing code to be run on an ARM hypervisor.

Comment: But one point still remains.... Would calling BX LR in do_IRQ make a return from interrupt or the control will go back to fault_handler

Comment: In this case, go back to `fault_handler`.

Comment: my confusion is here, if a mov pc, lr modifies PC and this instruction is treated as exit from interrupt. Why wont a BX LR treated as an exit from interrupt . (Say I am not delibrately using sub and lr is (-4) in a previous instruction to mov

Comment: A `mov pc, lr` is not an exit from interrupt - a `movs pc, lr` is (the `s` is special here that it restores the CPSR). If you've adjusted the lr in another instruction, it's perfectly fine to return from the interrupt with a `movs pc, lr`. A `bx lr` will not restore the CPSR and shouldn't be used to return from an exception.

Comment: Thanks a ton for clarifying the doubt! I think there needs to a cheatsheet for this.